# componentDidUpdate() keeps getting called infinitely

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I have this search component which updates the search result based on the value of the input from the user:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// import "React Router" components
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import custom components
import Book from "./Book";

// import required API
import * as BooksAPI from "../BooksAPI";

export default class BookSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    searchResult: [],
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ 
      query: e.target.value 
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(currentProps, currentState) {
    const { query, searchResult } = this.state;
    if (this.state.query !== currentState.query && query) {
      BooksAPI.search(query.trim()).then((books) =>
        this.setState({ searchResult: books })
      );
    } else if (query === "") {
      this.setState({
        searchResult: [],
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { query, searchResult } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <Link to="/" className="close-search">
            Close
          </Link>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by title or author"
              value={query}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-books-results">
          <ol className="books-grid">
            {searchResult.error ? (
              <p>No results matching your search</p>
            ) : (
              searchResult.map((book) => <Book key={book.id} book={book} />)
            )}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

even though I have conditions inside `componentDidUpdate()` but it keeps getting called when the input field is empty. What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(this.state.query !== currentState.query && query)` evaluates to false if query is an empty string and the `else if` statement doesn't test if `this.state.query` and `currentState.query` are the same.
Just move test for `state` and `currentState` up a level

```
 if (this.state.query !== currentState.query) {
  if(query){
    BooksAPI.search(query.trim()).then((books) =>
      this.setState({ searchResult: books })
    );
  } else if (query === "") {
  this.setState({
    searchResult: [],
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: So it is mandatory to always check if the new state or props are not the same as the previous ones or an infinite loop would occur? (btw it worked thank you so much)

Comment: You just need to make sure that if you are setting the state in `componentDidUpdate` that there is some condition that stops it from being setting every single time

Answer (score 0):

you are getting infinite loop error in both cases (if & else) you are setting state therefore it's re-render again & again and went to infinite loop error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your infinite loop is that you are calling a setState() within the componentDidUpdate, which will retrigger the cycle.

It looks like Books API is an asynchronous process.  I recommend looking at [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)